# Django - is_valid returns false for authentication built-in login form

Tags: python, html, django

Can anyone figure out why when I fill out the form it returns False for is_valid?

forms.py

```
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    class Meta:  
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
class LoginView(FormView):
    form_class = LoginForm
    template_name = 'login.html'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = LoginForm(self.request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponse('valid')
        else: 
            return HttpResponse('not valid')
```

login.html

```
    <form action "" method = "POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form|materializecss}}
        <button type = "submit">Login</button>
    </form>
```

As an extra, the following change to views.py returns the username and password so I know it has been passed to the POST request:

```
class LoginView(FormView):
    form_class = LoginForm
    template_name = 'login.html'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = LoginForm(self.request.POST)
        return HttpResponse (self.request.POST.get('username')+ ' ' +self.request.POST.get('password'))
```

Comment: What is `form.errors` returns?

Comment: Why have you added a meta class to the inherited form, and also adding model and fields attributes, from the implementation in Django I see that `AuthenticationForm` is not a `ModelForm`.

Comment: Also why not use `django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView` instead of inheriting `FormView`?